# define set compare function when set is the element of a vector

Tags: c++11

I want to define a vector of a set, and the define the set's compare function.

I know how to define the set compare function， like this:

```
bool isSmall(const std::pair<int, int> &i1, const std::pair<int, int> &i2)
{
    return i1.second < i2.second;
}
std::set<std::pair<int, int>, decltype(isSmall)*> set_int(isSmall);
```

But what if I have a  vector, and the vector element is my self-defined set?

```
std::vector< std::set<std::pair<int, int>, decltype(isSmall)*> > vec_set
```

this is not corret, since when I insert vec_set[0] another same element like <1,1> (<1,1> has been inserted into vec_set[0]) the program then crash down.

It seems that I should also do something like set_int(isSmall), but How can I do that when I define a vector containg this set like above?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, as you can see, i have a vector, and the element of this vector is my self-defined set, of which the element is pair<int ,int>. The core idea is that I want the set element rank according to the second int number of the pair<int ,int>, since the default rank rule rank the set according to the both int number in the pair<int ,int>, so I must define my own compare function and use this compare function when I define the set.

Comment: and I know how to do it now, just like what Qwabbelbelly says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't assign `isSmall` as comparator. (The template argument just specifies the type of it)

```
using T = std::pair<int, int>;

bool isSmall(T const & i1, T const & i2)
{
    return i1.second < i2.second;
}

void main()
{
    typedef bool(*CompareFunc)(T const &, T const &); // decltype(isSmall)*

    std::vector< std::set<T, CompareFunc> > vec_set;

    vec_set.push_back(std::set<T, CompareFunc>(isSmall)); // <-- assign the function in every set<>-constructor manually
    vec_set[0].insert({ 1,1 });
    vec_set[0].insert({ 1,1 });
}
```

You could also use functors instead of functions:

```
struct CompareFunc // : public std::binary_function<T, T, bool>
{
    bool operator()(T const &i1, T const &i2) const
    {
        return i1.second < i2.second;
    }
};

void main()
{
    std::vector< std::set<T, CompareFunc> > vec_set;

    vec_set.resize(1); // <-- comparator gets instantiated automatically
    vec_set[0].insert({ 1,1 });
    vec_set[0].insert({ 1,1 });
}
```

See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare

Comment: well, i got the idea. and I have tried it and now I know what I missed. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider to accept the answer.